# 3 секунды ожидания после результата в MySQL и готовым массивом PHP

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Заметил потерю времени в 3 секунды между получением результатов запроса в MySQL и выводом готового массива в PHP.

Запрос в базу данных MySQL касается выборки последних котировок курсов валют. Он выполняется с приемлемой скоростью:

```
Отображение строк 0 - 24 (174 всего, Запрос занял 0.5257 сек.)
```

Сам запрос выглядит так (не суть важно, но для справки приведу):

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE t1.*
FROM currencyexchangerates t1
LEFT JOIN currencyexchangerates t2
ON (t1.Symbol = t2.Symbol AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY Symbol ASC
```

Но страница PHP выдает результаты этого запроса в виде готового массива через 3,5 секунды. Сам код выглядит так:

```
$start = microtime(true);

$currency_result = mysqli_query($link, $currency_query);

if ($currency_result){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($currency_result)) {           
        $currency_exchange_rates_array[] = array(
            'iso' => (string) $row['Symbol'],
            'value' => (float) $row['PriceToUSD']
        );

    };

};

//Этот фрагмент будет выполнен за 0.0002 сек.       
echo json_encode($currency_exchange_rates_array);

$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
echo '[PHP time] ' . $time_elapsed_secs . ' seconds <br>';
```

В итоге полное построение страницы происходит за такое время:

```
[PHP time] 3.5079050064087 seconds
```

Вопросы такие: на что тратится дополнительные 3 секунды, и как мне сократить это время по максимуму? Это ведь в 7 раз дольше, чем вообще потрачено времени на запрос в базу данных!

Конфигурация такая:

```
Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19
Версия клиента базы данных: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev
PHP расширение: mysqli
Версия PHP: 5.6.19
```

Comment: сколько строк вытаскивается таким запросом? сколько секунд затрачивается на json_encode? Может он упаковывает долго большую инфу

Comment: Вот весь массив. Здесь нет ничего большого: [{"iso":"AED","value":3.6723},{"iso":"AFN","value":65.949997},{"iso":"ALL","value":124.699997},{"iso":"AMD","value":474.730011},{"iso":"ANG","value":1.77},...]

Comment: Всего вытаскивается 174 строки. Фрагмент $currency_result = mysqli_query($link, $currency_query) исполняется за 3,3 сек., на создание массива $currency_exchange_rates_array нужно 0.0005 сек, на json_encode - 0.0002 с.

Comment: Самое простое и очевидное решение - комментируйте куски кода по очереди и выявляйте, какой из них тратит больше всего времени.

Comment: Вот это только что и указал. Именно на mysqli_query и уходит это самое долгое время. Выходит, что сам запрос через PHP как-то долго связывается с сервером или долго обрабатывает результаты запроса, который на самом сервере делается за 0,5 сек.

Comment: @llaabbss, возможно, сервер с базой данных просто долго отвечает. Какая разница в скорости при самых простейших запросах?

Comment: Самый простой запрос (например, отобрать все записи, которые относятся к евро: SELECT * FROM `currencyexchangerates` WHERE Symbol = 'EUR') (226 строк в результате) занимает всего 0.0225 сек. Индекс построен и по id, и по Symbol (не уникальный).

Comment: Вы не понимаете ДАО: скрипт выполняется, пауза (чай попил, отдохнул), дальше продолжает выполняться... :)

Comment: 1) Попробуйте ПДО для работы с базой. 2) Если база удаленная (не на локальной машине вместе со скриптами), то это могут быть потери на соединение. 3) Этот вариант я описал в комментарии выше.

Comment: Будет ли какой нибудь выигрыш с unbufferred query?

Comment: Неа, выигрыша не просходит. Проблему решил тем, что для текущих котировок сделал отдельную таблицу и из нее выбираю просто все. Да, не очень красиво, зато реально очень быстро все происходит.

Comment: 3 секунды ерунда. Браузер ждёт ответа от сервера минуты две не менее.

Comment: Как дела с индексом на Symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Полной информации по вопросу нет, но можно уже сделать пару выводов из того, что видно:

> Отображение строк 0 - 24 (174 всего, Запрос занял 0.5257 сек.)

Во-первых, Вам выбралось только 25 строчек. Вы нажмите галочку "отобразить все" или что там в текущей версии надо нажимать.

Во-вторых, есть еще время, затрачиваемое на извлечение данных, а Вы для чего-то выбираете все данные. Хотя, возможно, phpmyadmin складывает и то и другое (тут я не уверен уже).

Answer (score -1):

Основное время при выборках из БД идет на авторизацию пользователя базы, проверку прав итд. Так что пытайтесь разумно использовать лишнее подключение к БД. И не забывайте их закрывать. А вот если у вас подозрение на долгое выполнение самого SQL запроса, то вам стоит выполнить его с [EXPLAIN](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/EXPLAIN.html).

Comment: 1. Соединение уже установлено. 2. Что за "лишнее соединение"? 3. Соединение закрывается автоматически по завершении работы скрипта (если не persistent). Или вы предлагаете для каждого запроса открывать, а потом закрывать соединение? Боюсь тут выигрыша в скорости не получится

Comment: EXPLAIN запроса покажет время выполнения(стоимость выполнения запроса) и количество данных которое необходимо передать по сети. Если запрос выполнился быстро, необходимо обратить внимание на обьем выборки, потому что именно эти данные будут передаваться по сети.
Если и тут все хорошо, и код у вас отличный. Добавьте средство мониторинга приложения... например newrelic. Это точно найдет причину.